# Can't load CSS stylesheet in moodle

Tags: html, css, html-email, moodle

I run a Moodle 2.9 server, and while configuring the email to be sent to the user, I created a CSS stylesheet to be included to format said email. However, when I try the email, it appears non-formatted. I'm putting the text in question in a php variable inside a config file in moodle like this.

```
$string['newusernewpasswordtext'] = '
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,500,500italic);

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,400italic);


@font-face{
font-family:FontAwesome;
src:url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix) format(\eot\'),
url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.woff) format(\'woff\'),
url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.ttf) format(\'truetype\'),
url(https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/font//fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome) format(\'svg\');
font-weight:400;font-style:normal;
}

@import url("http://xxx/mail.css");

h1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: #E52B38;
    font-family: \'Roboto\', sans-serif;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}


</style>
```

I also tried including or linking the css file from within the body tags, to no avail. I have seen that the fonts are being loaded since one single element on the email has an inline formatting and is being rendered accordingly. However, i do not want to resort to inline formatting.

Thanks and I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: Emails are a fickle beast.  Common wisdom dictates that all styles should actually be inlined, as some clients will strip out <style> and <link> blocks.  My suggestion would be to author the email as you normally would, than use an inliner tool.  Something like this: http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/ or even this: http://zurb.com/ink/inliner.php

Comment: Tried zurb and the pseudo elements got lost, as i was guessing they would. Thanks anyway

Comment: You're going to run into issues using pseudo's either way: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: thanks! i used a mixed solution, putting the complex elements in images and Voila!! i don't like it, is so 1996 but it works, so thanks!!

Comment: I hear ya, that's where we're still at for email :(

Comment: i need to show the current year in that same email (loaded automatically), any ideas? :)

Comment: Yea, it should probably be entered statically, either through your email build system or manually. When the email arrives, it'll be timestamped anyway, so it won't look funny if a user opens the email two years from now.  If you ABSOLUTELY must have that dynamic (boss is making you), use JavaScript's `new Date().getFullYear()` , and place the static year next to it in a <noscript> block.  That way you cover both bases as there will be email clients that do not support JS.

Comment: I took the lazy route and put it statically...thanks man!!